# keyboard or mouse response to draw line in psychopy

Tags: psychopy

I would like to create an experience in psychopy, I must briefly present a square frame, within which
a vertical line was printed. The line is extended downward from the center of the upper
edge of the square then this square disappears and will appear in its place a 2nd square without the vertical line, the participant must draw a line on this 2nd square. i wrote the code for the 1st part but i dont know how to do to let participant draw the line? some one have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: Hasn't this been answered here: https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/drawing-line-as-response/12505 ?

Comment: Just reviewing some posts - adding code would be helpful for anyone looking at providing a potential solution.